# Using a 1995 model M with a modern setup

Tags: keyboards, ibm-pc, old-hardware-adaptation

Looking to get my Model M keyboard working on a modern setup, I believe I need an active converter to go from PS/2 to USB. What adapter / part would be compatible with this keyboard?

Comment: I think asking for a store is off-topic.  If you ask for a part or adapter, that might be more on-topic here.

Comment: I did say which adapter I'm looking for. I need am active PS2 to USB adapter. I just want to know if anyone knows where to get it...

Comment: I believe this is off topic here. See [Do we want questions asking for software or other resources?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/357) and [Questions about spare parts](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/357) and to a lesser extent [Do we want list questions?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/357), all on [meta].

Comment: Unfortunately I'm going to have to put this question on hold. If you edit it to be about asking for suggestions of _parts_, I think it would qualify to be re-opened. Please don't take this personally; "on hold" is usually temporary if the question can be edited to be on-topic. For more information, see [this help center article](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or `@wizzwizz4` reply to this comment.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 in topic now? I just need a part and want to know if anyone knows how to get it without ordering online.

Comment: @Neb That would be off-topic; this site mostly focuses on the actual computers. If [the continents all moved around](https://what-if.xkcd.com/10/) the contents of this website would remain completely usable (that is, if the servers survived the event!).

Comment: When selecting a new, modern, desktop system for Linux, one of my requirements was a PS/2 port for my Model M. There are motherboards available that have these, and other legacy ports, if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 8):

Are you just looking for a generic PS/2 to USB adapter?

[Ziotek's SANOXY PS2 Keyboard To USB Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSJFJS) seems to have good reviews on Amazon and work well with older keyboards.

[image: PS2 to USB]

Comment: I use that exact one with a Model M. I think it's also the one advocated for and sold by clickykeyboards.com.

Comment: Does this support N-key rollover like a real PS/2 port does? Most of the (cheap) PS/2 -> USB adapters I've seen don't. And if this one doesn't, what advantage does it hold over its many cheaper competitors, like those you might find on Monoprice?

Comment: @CodyGray Model M keyboards can be quite power hungry, and cheaper adapters don't always deliver enough power. Both by hearsay because my keyboard is a USB variant so I don't really face this problem directly.

Comment: I think this will work, but this part on the canadian Amazon is $50, I was hoping to find it at a shop in the city? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It's probably a terrible test, but I have that adaptor connected to a Mac, and found that it was not achieving n-key rollover when tested via the keyboard viewer. Which keys it would simultaneously depict depended on their location and grouping — e.g. any continuous four starting from either the left or the right were no problem, but in the middle I seemed limited to two and it was fine with left, down and right cursors simultaneously but not with those three plus up — so I don't think I feel for any of the most obvious pitfalls in that test, but it leaves a bunch of unknowns.

Comment: @tommy Well, the IBM Model M doesn't actually support *full* N-key rollover, so if you were testing with an honest-to-goodness Model M, that would be the explanation. If it was another PS/2 keyboard that you know does support NKRO, then it seems that would be a fair test of the adapter.